# Finding a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n_2$ that satisfies a certain property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A\subset \mathbb{Z}_2^n$ such that cardinality of $A$ is not one. Fix $y\in A$, let $y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n$ be the individual bits of $y$ i.e. $y_i\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Let $W(y)$ be the Hamming weight of $y\in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$ i.e. the number of ones in $y$.

> I am trying to find an $A$ s.t. the value of the expression $$C(a)=(-1)^{y_a}+\sum_{j\neq a, 1\leq j\leq n}(-1)^{y_a+y_j}$$ is non zero, is the same for all $1\leq a\leq n$ and for all $y\in A$. I am not sure if such an $A$ exists though.

I had tried $A$ to be a set of $y$ of a given Hamming weight i.e. $W(y)=k$, for some $k$, for all $y\in A$ but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, sorry, could you tell me why does $\{101,110\}$ not work for example?

Comment: Unless I goofed up something for $C(a)$ to not depend on $a$ you need $y$ to have $k$ zeros and $k+1$ ones, and thus $n=2k+1$. Anyway, if this checks out, you can select any $A$ consisting of vectors of weight $k+1$ and length $2k+1$. No even length solutions exist.

Comment: Anyway, it feels like something is missing from the question. The constraints don't tie distinct vectors of $A$ to each other at all. What is the origin of the underlying problem?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see, that's correct, $y$ has to have $k$ zeros and $k+1$ ones. I was solving some other problem and if the above condition is met, then that problem would be easier.

Comment: @Average-user Yes, it does work, for $k=1$ in Jyrki's argument. I didn't check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was writing up this when the comments appeared:
$$C(a)=(-1)^{y_a}\left (1+\sum _{j\neq a}(-1)^{y_j}\right )=(-1)^{y_a}\left (1+|x_a|_0-|x_a|_1\right ),$$
so if $C(a)=C(b)$ and $y_a\neq y_b$ assume $y_a=0,$ then $1+|x_a|_0-|x_a|_1=|x_b|_1-1-|x_b|_0$ and then
$$2+|x_a|_0+|x_b|_0=|x_b|_1+|x_a|_1,$$
also $|x_a|_0=|x|_0-1=|x_b|_0-1$ and $|x_a|_1=|x|_1=|x_b|_1+1$ and so we get
$$2+|x_a|_0+|x_a|_0+1=|x_a|_1+|x_a|_1-1,$$
and so $$|x_a|_0+1=(2+|x_a|_0)=|x_a|_1=|x|_1.$$
So the condition is equivalent to having one more $1$ than $0's$.